# Shortest path to open a letter lock

Tags: code-golf, parsing

This quite literally came to me in a dream.

A common combination padlock design has letters on the dials so you can set the combination to a word. Unfortunately, I can't read, but I can count. Considering I am in a hurry, send the shortest path around the dials to open the 4 letter lock, given the current letters and the correct combination.

The lock is set up so that the downward direction means going through the alphabet forwards

`A->B->...Y->Z->A...`

and upwards is in reverse

`B->A->Z->Y....C->B->A->Z...`

One turn refers to moving one letter in either direction.

### Input

Any of

- two strings `"Position", "Combo"`
- a list of strings `["Position", "Combo"]`
- A list of each character in the position, and a list for the combo
  `['p1', 'p2' 'p3', 'p4'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']`

The order of position and combo may be switched but the letters cannot be rearranged or interleaved in any way.

### Output

A list of the number of turns and the directions in which to turn. The directions can be indicated however you want, but it must be consistent and it cannot be a number. It can be a single list of tuples, paired `[turns, direction]` or `[direction, turns]`
or two lists, one of turns and one of directions as long as direction[a] corresponds to turns[a]. Positive/Negative for Up/Down works as well. You can use either direction for zero turns or equidistant letters

### Test cases:

```
[position, combo] -> [[turn[1], direction[1]], [t[2],d[2]], ...]
["NLWX", "GOLF"] -> [[7, up], [3, down], [11, up], [8, down]]
["CODE", "COOL"] -> [[0, up], [0, up], [11, down], [7, down]]
["AUGH", "NOPE"] -> [[13, up], [6, up], [9, down], [3, up]]
```

Comment: we're code golfing dreams now?

Answer (score 9):

## [Uiua 0.8.0](https://www.uiua.org/), 10 bytes <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/SBCSUiua)</sup>

```
-13◿26+13-
```

[Try on Uiua Pad!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__RiDihpAgLTEz4pe_MjYrMTMtCgpGICJHT0xGIiAiTkxXWCIKIyMKRiAiQ09PTCIgIkNPREUiCiMjCkYgIk5PUEUiICJBVUdIIgojIwoiQUJDRCIgIlRFU1QiCgotICAgIyBzdWJ0cmFjdCB0aGUgc3RyaW5ncywgZ2V0IGRpc3RhbmNlcyBiZXR3ZWVuIGxldHRlcnMKKzEzICMgYWRkIDEzCuKXvzI2ICMgbW9kIDI2Ci0xMyAjIHN1YnRyYWN0IDEzCgojIwo=)

Outputs positive and negative values.

### 18 bytes <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/SBCSUiua)</sup>

```
+@a↥0⊃±⌵-13◿26+13-
```

[Try on Uiua Pad!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__RiDihpAgK0Bh4oalMOKKg8Kx4oy1LTEz4pe_MjYrMTMtCgpGICJOTFdYIiAiR09MRiIKIyMjCkYgIkNPREUiICJDT09MIgojIyMKCiJBQkNEIiAiVEVTVCIKCi0gICAjIHN1YnRyYWN0IHRoZSBzdHJpbmdzLCBnZXQgZGlzdGFuY2VzIGJldHdlZW4gbGV0dGVycworMTMgIyBhZGQgMTMK4pe_MjYgIyBtb2QgMjYKLTEzICMgc3VidHJhY3QgMTMK4oqDwrHijLUgIyBnZXQgdGhlIHNpZ25zIGFuZCBhYnNvbHV0ZSB2YWx1ZXMK4oalMCAgIyB0YWtlIHRoZSBtaW5pbXVtIHdpdGggMCwgdHVybnMgLTEgc2lnbnMgaW50byAwCitAYSAjIGFkZCAiYSIgdG8gdGhlIHNpZ25zLCBtYWtlcyB1cD0iYSIgYW5kIGRvd249ImIiCgojIyMK)

Outputs 2 arrays, values and letters. Up is "a" and down is "b".

### Explanation

```
-   # subtract the strings, get distances between letters
+13 # add 13
◿26 # mod 26
-13 # subtract 13
⊃±⌵ # get the signs and absolute values
↥0  # take the minimum with 0, turns -1 signs into 0
+@a # add "a" to the signs, makes up="a" and down="b"
```

Comment: It's a shame `⍜(+13|◿26)` is longer.

Comment: @chunes agreed.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
O_/æ%13
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98/Xv/wMlVD4//e1o8a5ijo2ik8aphrfbj94c59KlyH2x81rYn8/z@aK1rJzyc8QklHyd3fx00pVgco4Ozv4goUcPb394EIOIa6ewAF/PwDXJViuWIB)

A monadic link taking a list of two strings and returning a list of integers with negative integers as down and positive as up.

### Explanation

```
O       | To codepoints
 _/     | Reduce by subtraction
   æ%13 | Symmetric mod 13
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 51 bytes

```javascript
x=>y=>x.map((c,i)=>parseInt(c+57+y[i],36)%97%26-13)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q7S1q5CLzexQEMjWSdT09auILGoONUzr0QjWdvUXLsyOjNWx9hMU9XSXNXITNfQWPN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmka0np6ekp9PeIRSrCaE4@7v4wbkaHJhUejs7@IKV@js7@8DUvgfAA)

Output pos/neg

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 68 bytes

```javascript
x=>y=>x.map((c,i)=>[i=(c=parseInt(c+57+y[i],36)%97%26-13)<0,i?-c:c])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q7S1q5CLzexQEMjWSdT09YuOtNWI9m2ILGoONUzr0QjWdvUXLsyOjNWx9hMU9XSXNXITNfQWNPGQCfTXjfZKjlW839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaaRrSenp6Sn094hFKsJoTj7u/jBuRocmFR6Ozv4gpX6Ozv7wNS@B8A)

> The directions can be indicated however you want, but it must be consistent and it cannot be a number.

I don't understand why but here `true` and `false` used

Comment: its to avoid ambiguity with the number of turns

Comment: @pacman256 There is no ambiguity. Answers can just specify which comes first.

Comment: 72: `x=>y=>x.map((c,i)=>[(c=parseInt(c+'d'+y[i],36)%1297%26)>13?26-c:c,c>13])`

Comment: @tsh 71 is possible

Comment: Comment ruling allows sign to be used to differentiate UP and DOWN, so `x=>y=>x.map((c,i)=>(c=parseInt(c+'d'+y[i],36)%1297%26)>13?c-26:c)` should be valid for 65 (Probably more golfable too)

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>78</del> 75 bytes

A port of [@l4m2's Javascript code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269061/110802) in Scala.

Saved 3 bytes thanks to the comment of @l4m2

---

```scala
(x,y)=>x.zip(y).map{case(c,v)=>Integer.parseInt(s"${c}57${v}",36)%97%26-13}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY7LSsNAFIb3eYrD0MIMTAI19GIggtQLYjSLUhRCFuM4CSntJM6MtTHkSdx0Yzd9or6No8nK1c_5v8M539dBc7Zm_jFBriw_mJIoPY3Ll5XgBh5YIaFxAF5FBhkEgPHCqELmtAsSXizEW3InTUog_H43mTs73eMdrS3ZeZ9FhWvibVjVcKYF5nRre7stcqG8iikt7IA1GjS8HU8HzbZF1J-Q4fl0eDZxR37bnyyd3mFjhTBTuQ7gUilWJ51HSgJYysJA-GcLUNnWrCXOMHqMnp4RBXQbRzeIkP94Hl9d_-J5HEcdbp3-7X7f5Q8)

Comment: `${57}` => `57`

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 38 bytes

```r
\(s,t,`+`=utf8ToInt)(+s-+t--13)%%26-13
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY31WI0inVKdBK0E2yBAhYh-Z55JZoa2sW62iW6uobGmqqqRmZAGqp6b5qGkp9PeISSjoKSu7-Pm5KmsoKunUJ0tLmOQmlBrI5CtLGOQkp-eR6IaWgIE7SACsZyAfU7-7u4gvQ7-_v7wPUbwJTCGSDdMJPMkfU7hrp7gPT7-Qe4wvUbGsP0mcEYlgj9EMlYiCcWLIDQAA)

Port of [@Tbw's Uiua answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269063/55372).

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 42 bytes

```r
\(s,t)strtoi(paste0(t,57,s),36)%%97%%26-13
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3tWI0inVKNItLikryMzUKEotLUg00SnRMzXWKNXWMzTRVVS3NVVWNzHQNjaE67iXUJdjGaFRopuZoALUVF-RklmhU6CgpaWpypWnUKfn5hEco6SjUKbn7-7gpaSor6NopREeb6yiUFsTqKEQb6yik5JfngZiGhjBBC6hgLNgEZ38XV7AJzv7-PnATDGCK4QyQfphZ5igmOIa6e4BN8PMPcIWbYGgM02kGY1giTIBIxkJ8uWABhAYA)

Port of [@l4m2's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269061/55372).

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>73</s> 66 bytes

```r
\(s,t,`+`=utf8ToInt)Map(\(x,a=c(x,x-26))a[order(abs(a))[1]],+s-+t)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3nWI0inVKdBK0E2yBAhYh-Z55JZq-iQUaMRoVOom2yUCyQtfITFMzMTq_KCW1SCMxqVgjUVMz2jA2Vke7WFe7RBNq0t40DSU_n_AIJR0FJXd_HzclTWUFXTuF6GhzHYXSglgdhWhjHYWU_PI8ENPQECZoARWM5QLqd_Z3cQXpd_b394HrN4AphTNAumEmmSPrdwx19wDp9_MPcIXrNzSG6TODMSwR-iGSsRBPLFgAoQE)

Straightforward (?) implementation of the task.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ç`-13+₂%13-
```

Port of [*@Tbw*'s Uiua's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269063/52210), so also uses negative values for down and positive for up.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cHuCrqGx9qOmJlVDY93//6OVHEPdPZR0lPz8A1yVYgE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w@0JuobG2o@amlQNjXX/6/yPjlby8wmPUNJRcvf3cVOK1YlWcvZ3cQXynf39fcB8x1B3DyDfzz/AVSk2FgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ç            # Convert both strings in the (implicit) input-pair to a list of codepoint
             # integers
 `           # Pop and push both integer-lists separated to the stack
  -          # Subtract the values at the same positions from one another
   13+       # Add 13
      ₂%     # Modulo-26
        13-  # Subtract 13
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-lF`, 48 bytes

```perl
say+($_=(ord shift@F)-ord)-($_>13)*26for<>=~/./g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJbQyXeViO/KEWhOCMzrcTBTVMXyNHUBQrbGRprahmZpeUX2djZ1unr6af/twbqUNKFAyXr/34@4RFc7v4@blzO/i6uQMLfh8sx1N2Dy88/wPVffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9A0OD/7o5bgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 15 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
13-26|13+-⍥⎕UCS
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=MzTWNTKrMTTW1n3Uu/RR39RQ52AA&f=U3f393FTV0hTUPfzCY9Q51J39vf3AfOd/V1cgXw//wBXMN8x1N1DHQA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog-extended&m=train&n=f)

A tacit function which takes strings on the left and right and returns an array of positive and negative values. Port of my Uiua answer, but we have to get from letters to numbers first. This is done using [`⎕UCS`](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/Content/Language/System%20Functions/ucs.htm), which takes a string and converts to  Unicode code points.

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 45 bytes

```
=index(mod(code(A1:A4)-code(B1:B4)+13,26)-13)
```

Put the position in cells `A1:A4`, the combination in cells `B1:B4` and the formula in cell `C1`. The output will be in positive/negative integers.

Uses [Tbw](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269063/119296)'s method.

## Microsoft Excel for the web, 38 bytes

```
=MOD(CODE(A1:A4)-CODE(B1:B4)+13,26)-13
```

Only works in Excel versions that spill result arrays by default.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
Ｉ⁻¹³﹪⁻¹³Ｅθ⁻℅ι℅§ηκ²⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzczr7RYw9BYR8E3P6U0Jx9ZILFAoxBIgQX8i1Iy8xJzNDI1dRRgbMcSz7yU1AqNDB2FbE0Q0FEwMgPR1v//O4a6e3D5@Qe4/tctywEA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Similar to @Tbw's method, but subtracts the 13 in a different way to save bytes. (@l4m2's method would take 21 bytes in Charcoal.)

```
  ¹³                Literal integer `13`
 ⁻                  Vectorised subtract
      ¹³            Literal integer `13`
     ⁻              Vectorised subtract
         θ          First input
        Ｅ           Map over characters
            ι       Current character
           ℅        Ordinal
          ⁻         Subtract
               η    Second input
              §     Indexed by
                κ   Current index
             ℅      Ordinal
    ﹪               Vectorised modulo
                 ²⁶ Literal integer `26`
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 90 bytes

```
O$#`.
$.%`
¶

M!`..
(.).
$&-$1
%{`.*?([A-Z])(-?)(#*)\1.*
$2$.3
T`L`ZL`^.
T`ZL`L`.$
.-
#$&#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchLCsIwFEbh@b8LyU1JQnKhuoBSaq2D2AgqlfrgOnDgxIE4c18uwI3Fjs7Hed3fj@cta7MTnxMpYRBrwe8LbGbCDMN2ekWgEvoj7CpzqsN4sSZU1ihnzyU70Jx4gb1EGaNcedLUKEzgAEWFyrmPw9F3Ka6AJi1b36QUgfrQrX2ftu0f) Takes input on separate lines but link is to test suite that splits on commas for convenience. Explanation:

```
O$#`.
$.%`
¶

M!`..
```

Transpose the input.

```
(.).
$&-$1
```

Duplicate the starting letters, but prefixed with `-`s, to indicate these copies are the ones going backwards.

```
%{`
```

Repeat the rest of the script on each line separately.

```
.*?([A-Z])(-?)(#*)\1.*
$2$.3
```

If the current line contains two identical letters, record the count of how long it took with the sign if appropriate.

```
T`L`ZL`^.
```

Advance the first letter forwards.

```
T`ZL`L`.$
```

Wind the last letter backwards.

```
.-
#$&#
```

Increment the count.